# Raspberry pi 3 B+ solid red light, was working before

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

So I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and installed the Raspbian stretch with desktop onto my SD card.  The first time I booted it up, it worked great!  I was having trouble installing some python libraries.  I decided to start again from scratch, and reformat the SD card and put a fresh OS on it.  I'm using the official SD card formatter, and did a full overwrite on the card.  I rewrote the OS image to the card, but now am stuck with a solid red light on start up.  No ACT light at all, no image on the screen.  I swapped it with a new SD card, and downloaded the Raspbian zip file again.  Still nothing.  I tried using the Raspbian stretch lite, still nothing.

Has anyone run into this problem?  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Is the SD card hot ?